# How can an anaconda package require two channels to install?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I just tried to install some packages into a fresh environment. I tend to specify channels for each install e.g. `conda install -c <channel> <package>`, rather than using `conda config --add channels <channel name>`; `conda install <package>`. However, I found that certain packages could only be installed when using multiple channels at once. How can this work?

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how packages and channels work. How can a package install require multiple channels? It was my understanding that a particular channel hosted particular packages, e.g. `conda-forge` hosts x packages and they (and their dependencies) are installable using just `conda-forge`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem with hosting all packages and all their dependencies is that some dependencies would have to be packaged multiple times by different channels, which creates unnecessary work/problems. Some channel developers decide to build their channels compatible (actually depending on theses channels) to more general channels (like conda-forge) to avoid excessive re-packaging.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> It was my understanding that a particular channel hosted particular packages, e.g. `conda-forge` hosts x packages and they (and their dependencies) are installable using just `conda-forge`.

That is not necessarily true.  If there is a package that lower-level package that is required as part of an install, but it is only hosted on, perhaps, the default channels, it is often easier to just list it as a requirement than to try to get the originated to post it to multiple channels.

You can always chain together multiple channels in a single conda command as well.

```
conda install <package> -c defaults -c conda-forge -c <other channel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would this look like in the actual `meta.yml` for building the package as an author?

Comment: @QuantumChris unfortunately the `meta.yaml` does not allow channel specification, AFAIK. Instead, one can use the `-c|--channel` flag in `conda-build` when building. Admittedly, this is an underspecification of the true dependencies, but it seems unavoidable in the context that users always have the choice of channel priorities during `conda install`. If you plan on maintaining a channel, then providing users with a recommended channel priority seems the way to go (e.g., [Bioconda does this](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels)).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In complement, according to the defined `channel_priority` the order of the channels specified in the command line will be taken (or not) into account. See `conda config --describe channel_priority` for more information.

Comment: @Roman, yes, the channels are prioritized in the order in which they are listed.  I always place `defaults` first because I prefer that channel, but some folks use conda-forge as their primary.